# Javamail attach multiple files

Tags: jakarta-mail

The following code sends mail and attachments as well via gmail smtp server using javamail api.

```
    public void doSendGmail(){
    from = txtFrom.getText();
    password= new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
    to = txtTo.getText();
    cc = txtCC.getText();
    bcc = txtBCC.getText();
    subject = txtSubject.getText();
    message_body = jtaMessage.getText();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);

    try {
        //message definition
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        if(!cc.equals("")){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(cc));
        }
        if(!bcc.equals("")){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse(bcc));
        }
        message.setSubject(subject);
        if(!filename.equals("")){// if a file has been attached...
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(message_body);// actual message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();// create multipart message

            // add the text message to the multipart
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // attachment part
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String attachment = fileAbsolutePath;
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachment);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);//add the attachment to the multipart message
            // combine text and attachment
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // send the complete message
            Transport.send(message, from, password);
        }
        else{// if no file has been attached
            message.setText(message_body);
            Transport.send(message, from, password);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message Sent!","Sent",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
    }
}
```

This code can only attach and send one file at a time. How do you enable it to attach multiple files and send them as one email?

The file is attached using a JFileChooser as shown below:

```
public void doAttachFile(){
    try {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        filename = file.getName();// get name of selected file
        lblFileName.setText(filename);// display name of selected file
        fileAbsolutePath= file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("File name: "+filename+"\n"+"Absolute path: "+fileAbsolutePath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No file was attached");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a "for" loop around the attachment part.

Comment: I'm using JFileChooser to attach the file (as you can see from the edited source code). How do you store the attached files say for example in an array so that you can then use a for loop to add the attached files to the message. Only the last file to be attached will be sent if the code remains as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're confused about very basic Java programming or about how to use JFileChooser to select multiple files.  I believe JFileChooser will only let you choose one file at a time, so you're going to need a loop around your use of JFileChooser, and some way for the user to say "I'm done choosing files".  Each iteration adds the chosen file to an array or List or whatever.

Comment: I'm not really confused about using JFileChooser to select multiple files but rather how to add the multiple attachments to the multipart. I was thinking of creating an array to add whatever file is attached and then add the array to the multipart after i'm done attaching the files. The question is, what data type will be the array so that it can be able to hold files

Comment: After attaching each of the files, there's no need to attach the array; the message already contains all the files.  Collect the files in an array if you want, then iterate over the array and attach each file to the message, throwing away the array when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple files you can implement this.

```
// Adds multiple attachments    
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

String[] attachFiles = new String[amountFiles];
attachFiles[0] = "path.pdf";
attachFiles[1] = "path.txt";

if(attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0){
    for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
        MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        try {
            attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
    }
}

message.setContent(multipart);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can attach as many files as you want just repeat this line

```
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

for every file